# How to Import subcategories CSV?

Tags: magento

I want to import CSV with it's multiple catgories. There is parent category and multile category. Suppose in below exam I need to save dl(Subcat) then should be save under `default(cat) -> manza(Subcat) ->manza 20 (Subcat)->manca xl(Subcat) ->dl(Subcat)`

Like I have by below code

```
parent cat  child cat-1  child cat-2  child cat-3 child cat-4    name 
deafult      manza        manza 20     manca xl   dl              dl

means:

name   path
dl     deafult/manza/manza 20/manca-xl/dl
```